# Send Ctrl + + (Ctrl+Plus) to a Windows application

Tags: windows, automated-tests, desktop-application, autoit

I have a Windows desktop application where I want to press Ctrl + + with AutoIt, it should open a new window (or increase font size in Chrome/Firefox/etc).
I don't know why but it doesn't work.

I tried it with [Send()](https://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/docs/functions/Send.htm) in several ways without success.

My latest .au3 code:

```
Local $hWnd = "[REGEXPTITLE:(?i)(.*App Window Title*.)]"
WinActivate($hWnd) ; WinActivate finds the window and activates it
Sleep(500)
Send("{CTRLDOWN}{+}")
Send("{CTRLUP}")
```

Previous attempts:

`Send("^{+}")` based on documentation, nothing happens

`Send("{LCTRL}{+}")` it writes a plus sign to the active input field

`Send("^{ASC 043}")` it writes a plus sign to the active input field

```
Send("{CTRLDOWN}")
Sleep(500) ; with and without sleep
Send("{+}")
Send("{CTRLUP}")
```

When I tried `Send("^p")` in Chrome it opened the print preview window (Ctrl+P).

Comment: read the help of `send`. It takes a second parameter (flag). You'd need RAW to not translate the `+` to `SHIFT`

Comment: `Send("^{+}", 1)` would result _^{+}_ in the active input field.

Comment: I thought more of `send("{ctrldown}")`, `send("+",1)`, `send("{ctrlup}")`. Both RAW and DEFAULT in the same `send` won't work.

Comment: btw:  your approach `Send("^{+}")` works for me (increases fontsize in Chrome)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is: `Send("^{NUMPADADD}")` or `Send("^{NUMPADMULT}")`

In Chrome only the NUMPADADD works.

Comment: In my case both works. In Chrome only `Send("^{NUMPADADD}")`